# Push down a <div> under another clickable <div> that has float and clear

Tags: html, css

I have a  class called "car-name". Within "car-name" I have the "car-image", "car model", and "car-feedback", all three with separate  classes because I style each of them differently. Now the whole  "car-name" needs to be clickable like an image. I kinda managed that but within JSfiddle the opacity does not work (I guess?). Now the  called "description" also floats right next to my car-image, which I do not want. How to push  description down under the last line of the clickable "car-name" ?

Here Fiddle...[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rabas007/bk57a89u/20/)

HTML

```
<div class="car-name">
    <a href="/our-cars" &text="carmake">
                    <div class="car-image"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/100x100">
                        bestcarmodel
                        <div class="car-review">feedback nnnnnnnnnnnnnn nnnnnnnnnnnnnn nnnnnnnn nnnnnnnnnn nn</div></div></a>

    <div class="description">this belongs under the clickable part --- ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo oo o o o o ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo o o o oooooooooooooooooooooooo                   o oo o ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo              oooooooooooooooooooooo o o</div>
```

CSS

```
.car-image {
    height:45px;
    width:45px;
    padding:0 0 5px 55px;
    position:relative;
    word-wrap: break-word; 
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    display:inline-block;
}

.car-image img {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    left: 0;
    position:absolute;
}

.car-review {
    padding:0 0 10px 0;
    width:150%;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.car-name:hover {
    opacity:1.5;
}
```

Comment: Add clear: both/left for your description class

Comment: Opacity doesn't work because it should be a number between 0 and 1.. I think you meant 0.5?

Comment: @Syahrul - tried that, didnt work because I need description class to be right under the last line of my car-review class and not under the image. The car-review class has break-word and I want to keep that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an issue with your markup, the `<a>` and `<div>` tags are not being closed in the right order so they are interleaved and not nested.
Once the markup is fixed, it should work.

Try this:

```
<div class="car-name"> 
    <a href="/our-cars" &text="carmake">
        <div class="car-image"><img alt="" src="http://placehold.it/100x100"/</div>
        bestcarmodel
        <div class="car-review">feedback nnnnnnnnnnnnnn nnnnnnnnnnnnnn nnnnnnnn nnnnnnnnnn nn</div>
    </a>
</div>
<div class="description">this belongs under the clickable part --- ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo oo o o o o ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo o o o oooooooooooooooooooooooo o oo o ooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooo oooooooooooooooooooooo o o</div>
```

Then to the CSS add a clear to push the description below the whole thing

```
.description { clear: both; }
```

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/zzella/rpgvoc34)

Comment: I need the car-review class to be as in my Fiddle with break-word and limited width. The description class should go under the last line of the car-review class and not under the image.

Comment: Then remove the .description class and it will do that: updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/zzella/rpgvoc34/